# Why we can approximate function

Tags: complex-analysis

Why we can uniformly approximate function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ with complex polynomials in $\{|z| = 1\}$ $\cap$ $\{Im (z) \geqslant 0\}$? Is it connected with the fact , that this function is holomorphic there ?

Comment: Any holomorphic function  on a simply connected region can be uniformly approximated by polynomials on any compact subset. [See Rudin's RCA for  a proof]. Can yo u write down a simply connected region  which does not contain $0$ but contains the set on which you are trying to approximate?